# Multiplication values in JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I want to multiple price and quantity, so i can get the total, and put it in the table too. Can you help me? Because I already search other reference and add `public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {}` but I got error so I delete it -_-

```
try {
            String trans_id = txtNo.getText();
            String menu_id = txtMID.getText();
            String quantity = txtQuan.getText();
            String menu_price = "";

            Statement stmt;
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menu");
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into transaction (trans_id, menu_id, menu_price, quantity)"
                    + "values ('" + trans_id + "','" + menu_id + "','" + menu_price + "','" + quantity + "')");

            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblMenu.getModel();
            if (rs.next()) {
                txtNo.setText("" + rs.getString("trans_id"));
                txtMID.setText("" + rs.getString("menu_id"));
                menu_price = rs.getString("menu_price");
                txtQuan.setText("" + rs.getString("quantity"));

                model.addRow(new Object[]{trans_id, menu_id, menu_price, quantity});
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed" + e);
        }
```

Really need your help.

Comment: what are `txtNo`, `txtMID` and `txtQuan`

Comment: `txtNo` = Bill Number , `txtMID` = menu id, `txtQuan` = Quantity / amount

Comment: I did not ask you what these classes represent in the program but what are the types as you have used the method `setText` in all of them

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to first convert price and quantity to numerical values, multiply them, and then convert the product back to a String. You can convert the text values of price and quantity using Integer.parseInt(String s). Or Double.parseDouble if your price is not an integer...you get the idea. Do that for both price string and quantity string. Then you can get the String value by String.valueOf(whatever your price * quantity value is), assuming you want to put that value into the table as a String.

Comment: can you make the coding for me? ._. I tried it, but I confused how to make menu_price bcs I didnt get it from textfield but from database.